# How to format a string to date in tibco spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am unable to parse a string which looks like "04/20/2016" to date format in Tibco spotfire. Strings of format "04-20-2016" is been parsed to date when I use parseDate("04-20-2016","MM-dd-yyyy"), but the same function doesn't work for "04/20/2016" the result is just empty.

I can simply use Date("04/20/2016") which successfully parses the string to 20-Apr-2016, but when I open the same in web Player its again empty, It works only when I open the .dxp file in my local machine.

Comment: just to be clear, you are updating the function from parseDate("04-20-2016","MM-dd-yyyy") to parseDate("04/20/2016","MM/dd/yyyy"), correct?

Comment: Yes.!!! though you use parseDate("04/20/2016","MM/dd/yyyy"), the out put is still empty.!!

Comment: if you are trying to convert the entire column I would use a transformation to change the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue in the thick client. as a workaround, you can use `Substitute()` to replace `/` with `-`:

```
ParseDate(Substitute([d],'/','-'), "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

it's also worth noting that if your date format is `mm-dd-yyyy` and your date is `4/20/2016`, `ParseDate()` won't be able to parse it (it's expecting a leading 0 for the `mm`).

---

I don't have access to a Web Player instance to check the `Date()` function, but I would suggest to check the regional settings on the Web Player machine and make sure it's the same format as the incoming date (i.e., if the format is `dd/mm/yyyy` on the host machine, it will try to parse `04/20/2016` and fail as there's no 20th month).

Comment: Thank you, using substitute fixes my issue for now as i noticed that the string which i get is of format 04/20/2016 and not 4/20/2016.

Comment: Definitely check your format string and make sure it's not expecting a two-digit month in that case

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for dates without leading 0, you can implement:

```
ParseDate(Substitute([StringDate],"/","-"),"d-M-yyyy")
```